# SwiftUI change SecureField masking character

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

SwiftUI on MacOS 11

The objective is to have a SwiftUI SecureField display a Unicode character different than the default bullets (••••••), for example an emoji, a randomly generated character, etc. An important part of the objective is that the *actual* text input by the user is fully editable and preserved, and accessible in a `@State` variable, and the masking characters are only displayed, but I don't mind if it's achieved with a TextField or some other View instead.

For example, the vanilla SecureField bullets:

```
struct ContentView : View {

  @State var password : String = ""

  var body: some View {

    VStack {
      SecureField("Password", text: $password)
      Button("Transmogrify!") {}
    }.padding()

  }
}
```

which results in this:

[image: standard SecureField output]

The objective is to achieve the same behaviour as a SecureField, but displaying a different character like this:

[image: modified SecureField output]

So far I have not been able to come up with a working code example.
I have tried using a plain `TextField` in conjunction with an explicit `Binding<String>` to attempt to control the underlying text `get`/`set` but due to the nature of bindings that affects the text ultimately stored in `password`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a proxy

```
import SwiftUI
//Shows a sample use
@available(iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, *)
struct SecureParentView: View{
    @State var text: String = "secure"
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(text)
            MySecureFieldView(text: $text)
        }
    }
}
//The custom field
@available(iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, *)
struct MySecureFieldView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    //The proxy handles the masking
    var proxy: Binding<String>{
        Binding(get: {
            return text.map { _ in "\u{272A}" }.joined() 
        }, set: { value in
            //Not needed here because the TextField is focused
        })
    }
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Int?
    var body: some View {
        //This is for size. The 3 layers have to match so the cursor doesn't look off
        Text(text).lineLimit(1)
            .opacity(0)
        //Put a true secure field on top that has invisible text/dots
            .overlay(
                SecureField("actual", text: $text)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: 1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.2)
                
            )
            .background(
                //This will sit on below but will look like it is on top
                //It will reduce in size to match lettering
                Text(proxy.wrappedValue)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.2)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                    .opacity(1)
            )
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.clear))
            .onTapGesture {
                focusedField = 1
            }
    }
    
}

@available(iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, *)
struct SecureParentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecureParentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering, this helps my understanding greatly! This solution works perfectly if the user enters characters at the end or deletes characters at the end of the input. It becomes problematic though, if more complex input is performed, like inserting a character at the middle of the input, or copying and pasting sequences in arbitrary parts of the string. Are you familiar with an approach that could elegantly account for those? I could design a string comparer algorithm, but that seems suspiciously complex for this objective.

Comment: @batanasov Yeah that would take a little more thought. Like finding the alpha characters from the value. That is why I clear the string when the change is more than one. You could also add a check for an alpha in between the special characters and clear it then. Maybe adding the option for showing the password. Usually when people are making special changes they show the password. It just depends on how much work you want to put into it.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as this is potentially completely workable (Apple made this a bit harder than it needs to be :D ) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @batanasov I added an iOS 15 macOS 12 version. It is slightly better. The `TextField` is focused so it will act better in more cases but copy and paste won't work. It likely could with a little customization

Comment: I think I'll need to familiarise myself with @FocusState a little bit for this one. I'll post my solution as well once I adapt this to work with copy, paste, replace etc. Thank you again for the detailed work!

Comment: This is pretty good (it works!) but I would suggest polishing a bit. For example, the binding getting can just be simplified down to `text.map { _ in "\u{272A}" }.joined()` or `String(repeating: "\u{272A}", count: text.count)`

Comment: @batanasov I was working on something else and came up with a better version. The cursor works better.