# How to partially mask a token key in SwiftUI TextField

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI app where I have a TextField for entering a token key. I would like to partially mask the token key, showing only the first few characters and replacing the rest with a masking character (e.g. "*"). However, the SecureField in SwiftUI masks the entire input.

I've tried customizing the `SecureField` by subclassing it and overriding its `textContentType`, but that did not provide the desired result. I also attempted modifying the `CustomSecureField` code provided in Apple's documentation, but it still masks the entire input.

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    @Binding var settingsShown: Bool
    @Binding var messages: [Message]

    @AppStorage("authToken") var authToken: String = ""

    // ... other code ...

    private var authTokenField: some View {
        HStack {
            SecureField("Enter your auth token here", text: $authToken)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                .padding(4)
                .padding(.horizontal, 4)
                .background(Color(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2).cornerRadius(6))
            
            // ... other code ...
        }
        .padding().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }

    // ... other code ...
}

struct Message {
    // ... message properties ...
}
```

This is what I want:
[image: This is what I want]

This I what I get:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI change SecureField masking character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69691527/swiftui-change-securefield-masking-character)

Comment: That post looks like my issue now, I get the token masked, but I am trying to get it only partially masked @loremipsum

Comment: Just modify the return line in the proxy to display whatever you want.

Comment: I was actually able to solve it with a different approach. You can close the question pls. @loremipsum

Comment: [Deleting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: [Closing posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: It would be nice if you post your own solution as an answer or at least, give a hint which was your "different approach". [Answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a proxy variable to change the displaying value on the fly:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var actualToken: String = ""
    var displayToken: Binding<String> { 
        .init { actualToken.enumerated().map { String($0.offset < 4 ? $0.element : Character("*")) }.joined() }
         set: { actualToken = $0 }
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Token", text: displayToken) // <- Uses the proxy instead of actual token
    }
}
```